# How can i delay a .css function before animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i checked other posts similar to mine, but none of the codes worked, 
So how can i add some delay to .css before my animation

here you can find my code below :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.div2')
        .css('visibility', 'visible') <-- // I WANT TO ADD HERE A DELAY BEFORE THE ANIMATION THAT IS BELOW STARTS !!!!
          .animate({opacity: 1.0, left: '600px'}, 2000);


        $('.div2').animate({opacity: 0.0, left: '600px'}, 2000, setInvisible);
      });

      function setInvisible() {
        $('.div2').css('visibility', 'hidden');
      }
```

i want to delay the css, so the div will be appeared with delay, and animation will start a bit later.

here is the Fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/Rroni/4b56n6p1/

Comment: Reproduce your code using fiddle.

Comment: if you delay the css, animation also will get further delayed

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Rroni/4b56n6p1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4b56n6p1/1/

Comment: @wiesion in your case, visibility of div is not delayed, the animation is delayed.. i want to delay the visibility of div

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4b56n6p1/2/

Comment: @wiesion this works, thanks but how can i make other divs, so they will be animated one by one, (for example: div1 animate to left, then fadeOut, then div2 appears, animates to left, then fadesOut.. etc)

Comment: i get the feeling that your primary goal is to animate your page, i wouldn't recommend using jQuery for this, instead have a look at animation frameworks like http://greensock.com/gsap

Answer (score 3):

Use [**.delay()**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) as shown :-

```
$('.div2')
    .css('visibility', 'visible')
     .delay(1000)  //this time is in milliseconds increase or decrease as required.
      .animate({opacity: 1.0, left: '600px'}, 2000);
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4b56n6p1/5/)

**OR** As per questioner comment, try using `setTimeout()` as shown :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.div2')
            .css('visibility', 'visible')
              .animate({opacity: 1.0, left: '600px'}, 2000);
    },1500)  //this time is in milliseconds increase or decrease as required.
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4b56n6p1/4/)

Comment: i want to delay the css so the div's visibility will be delayed.. not the animation !